# How to type Japanese using kana input (かな入力) using an ANSI keyboard

Tags: keyboard, ime, japanese

I'm using an ANSI Keyboard with a thinclient on a customer's VDI using Windows 7 Japanese OS. 
[image: ansi keyboard]
and when I change IME mode to kana input (かな入力)　I can't type `ろ/ロ` character because no key on the keyboard could generate it.
when I touch the

```
`
```

key on my keyboard, it change between `A mode` and `あ mode` in Japanese instead of insert `ろ/ロ` to the stream

How could I config to use kana input (かな入力) on an ANSI keyboard?

### [image: 2]

UPDATE: 
I've tried some searches, on my friend's P